# regex - get last occurrence before match

Tags: python, regex

With regex, from the following sentence

```
my name is oscar my name is oscar my name is oscar my name is david my name is oscar
```

I would like to get the "oscar" immediately previous to david (in this case would be the 3rd "oscar")

I've tried many things but none of them have worked.

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: *I've tried many things* - show them. And perhaps, some of those could be adjusted a little instead of writing from scratch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
oscar(?=(?:(?!oscar).)*david)
```

Find an "oscar" such that it is followed by any number of characters that do not start an "oscar", followed by a "david".